# How many memory references are required by the CPU to execute immediate address instruction and why?

Tags: cpu, addressing-mode, immediate-operand

In immediate addressing mode I know that instead of operand's address we have the value of operand in the instruction itself.
So, does CPU requires any memory reference as the effective address of the operand is the instruction's address itself.

Any insights would be very much helpful.

Comment: What's a "memory reference"? If you meant memory *access* then none is required (if you exclude the fetching of the instruction).

Comment: I think in the question memory reference means calculation of Effective operand address and fetching it. But actually it is not very clear to me also what it means by memory reference.